# Sub-query in generate_series-function?

Tags: postgresql

Long story short; I need to generate all dates between two given dates. My first instinct is just the `generate_series` function, so something like

```
\set start_date '''2019-10-01'''
\set end_date '''2019-11-07'''

SELECT current_date+AllDates.days
FROM generate_series(DATE :start_date-current_date,
DATE :end_date-current_date) AS AllDates(days);
```

which basically is some adapted code from the psql 9.5 documentation. This works, but I would like to get the `start_date` and `end_date` from the simple queries

```
SELECT min(checkout_date)
FROM table;
```

and

```
SELECT max(checkout_date)
FROM table;
```

How can I achieve this? Is there a better overall approach? I do realize the main problem with the two small queries is that they generate a table with the value and not the date-value in itself, but since I'm pretty new to SQL I have a hard time to grasp how one handles these situations.

Comment: in general, it's not a problem at all that these mini-queries responds with the series. Something like this should work:

select * from 
  generate_series(
      (select min(date) from dates), 
      (select max(date) from dates), 
      '1 day')

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/70f8f/3

Can you say more about the table you use to obtain checkout_date?

Comment: Ah alright, then I just focused on the wrong thing. The syntax-error I got was simply because I omitted the '1 day', and not due to the queries producing a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with my_table(checkout_date) as (
values 
    ('2019-01-01'::date),
    ('2019-01-03'::date)    
)

select generate_series(min(checkout_date), max(checkout_date), interval '1 day')
from my_table;

    generate_series     
------------------------
 2019-01-01 00:00:00+01
 2019-01-02 00:00:00+01
 2019-01-03 00:00:00+01
(3 rows)
```

Note that you need the third `interval` parameter. Read about set returning functions [in the documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html)